# how to get a thumbnail from a video on the external storage or form documentFile or threeUri?

Tags: android, inputstream, video-thumbnails

I used below code but it returns null for bitmap :

```
DocumentFile documentFile = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(getBaseContext(),Uri.parse(externalPrefs));
Bitmap bitmap=ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(documentFile .getUri().getPath(), MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
```

how to get thumbnail from documentFile or threeUri ?
is there any way to get thumbnail from InputStream of video ?

Comment: What is the value of externalPrefs? What is the value of documentFile.getUri().getPath()?

Comment: externalPrefs is the path of video file on the SD card its value is : `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/E23C-61E0%3A14-05-2018_12-59-03.mp4` and `documentFile.getUri().getPath() ` value is : `/tree/E23C-61E0:/document/E23C-61E0:14-05-2018_12-59-03.mp4`

Comment: Well a content:// scheme is no path to a file on the file system. And the /tree/... is also not a path to a file on the file system. I think createVideoFile() expects a valid file system path.

Comment: so how explorer apps getting thumbnail from all files such videos or images ? like RootExplorer

Comment: Dont know. Ask the developers. They could ask the MediaStore for a thumbnail too. Try with something like             bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri); There are functions to ask for a thumbnail too i think.